# Is there a way to define optional arguments after not defining other optional arguments when calling a Python function?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function called fruit:

```
def fruit(a="Apples",b="Bananas"):
    print(a,b)
```

I want to change the value of b to Blueberries instead of Bananas when I call the fruit function.

At the moment, I have to do:

```
fruit("Apples","Blueberries")
```

Calling the function like this is a problem because it forces me to define the first "Apples" part of the function, and also takes me longer to write.

Instead, I want to do something like:

```
fruit(,"Blueberries")
```

Although I know this example wouldn't work because of the hanging comma.

I have already tried:

```
fruit(None,"Blueberries")
```

But this doesn't work because the None value is assigned to the Apples.

Is there any way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the keyword argument:

```
fruit(b="Blueberries")
```

Or change the function to:

```
def fruit(a=None, b=None):
    a = a or "Apples"
    b = b or "Bananas"
    print(a, b)
fruit(None, "Blueberries")
```